# Kernel restart when using simple matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, kernel

I would like your help with a simple issue.
I'm on spider 5.15, with matplotlib on 3.4.3, on windows 10, on python 3.8.

My problem is when I start a code with matplotlib my kernel crashes and restarts.
The simplest way to reproduce my error is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2])
```

I suspect the version on matplotlib and I try to downgrade it from 3.4.3 down to 3.1.

I try `matplotlib.use("Agg")` or `("Qt5Agg")`

I try to downgrade all the versions but still did not work.